# How to cache login data AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, caching, authentication

I have recently attempted to create a login page that when the user logs in, a pop-up box appears asking them if they want to save their credentials. And if yes then the next time the user goes onto the login page, the ID & Password are already filled out. Plus the pop-up is never seen again unless they're a new user. Can someone show me how to cache the login data?

**JS:**

```
//Check login credentials against db
          $http.post('http://178.32.64.76:8765/login', {
            IDNumber: $scope.login.IDnumber,
            password: $scope.login.password
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.status = response.status;
              var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                template: 'Do you want to save your login credentials?',
                okText: 'Yes',
                cancelText: 'No'
              });

              confirmPopup.then(function(popupResponse) {
                if (popupResponse) {
                //Caching code will go here

              }

              $state.go('tab.dash');
              });
```

**Input:**

```
<input name="IDnumber" type="text" placeholder="ID Number"
ng-model="login.IDnumber" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" numbers-only required>

<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"
ng-model="login.password" required>
```

Comment: Please be aware that filling out the password field is a very bad practice, as anyone with a little knowledge about web inspection tools could see what's hidden behind the stars of the password field. You should instead want to override the login page. I.E. if the login page detects persisted credentials it doesn't displays the form but rather goes back to the previous page or the index

Comment: This is for a demo purpose, doesn't need protection at the minute. It's just for when its being demoed to people, I don't have to re-enter the credentials again and again

Comment: Then maybe you just need your browser to store these credentials? If there is no prompt, make sure you didn't disable the functionality in your browser configuration and that the form is correctly recognized as a login form (I think an input with type="password" is the criteria) ; the popup would then be replaced by your browser prompting you for credentials storage

Comment: So shall I be using $localstorage to save these credentials and need to make sure the web browser isn't disabling the function?

Comment: You don't even need $localstorage, browsers have been saving credentials from the dawn of time without any additional (website) code. When I log in a website my browser (be it IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera) will ask me if I want to remember these credentials. If I accept, next time I visit the page it will automatically fulfill the fields with the values it persisted in its own secure storage.

Comment: To be accurate it doesn't even really fills the password field, it just puts stars here and only when the form is submitted will it send the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$localStorage` of the `$window` object to store your user data. This data will be persisted until the browser cache is cleared.

Although it would be better if you don't store your username and password. Instead, you can store a login status. Say, a user logged in, now you can store a token in localstorage with value set to true and use it later to log in the user directly.

Comment: This is for a demo purpose, doesn't need protection at the minute. It's just for when its being demoed to people, I don't have to re-enter the credentials again and again

Comment: then use $localstorage